# Image with text partial overflow using css

Tags: html, css, image, overlapping

I am trying to achieve following output -

[image]

But having trouble with that partial overlap at the bottom of each pic. I can have them separated out (see the code at the end of this post). I can put negative margin on the div that is below the images, but that puts text on image without white background covering the picture.

Couple of restrictions -
With the tool i am working, I have to stick with inline css, no grid or flexbox. And it needs to be responsive i.e. work with changing browser size (so probably providing fixed height and width in pixels will not work).

What i have below works well as far as responsiveness goes. But not able to achieve that partial overlap along with white background. Here is what i have so far

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="overflow: auto">
        <img src="images/SIFT_Video.png" style="display:inline-block;max-width: 47%;min-width: 47%; float: left"/>
        <img src="images/SIFT_User_Guide.png" style="display:inline-block;max-width: 47%;min-width: 47%; float: right"/>
    </div>
    <div style="clear: both"></div>
    <div>
        <table style="table-layout: fixed ; width:100%">
            <tr>
                <td style="width:2%"></td>
                <td style="width:43%;text-align: left;color:#00AFAB;vertical-align:top">SIFT Video</td>
                <td style="width:10%"></td>
                <td style="width:43%;text-align: left;color:#00AFAB;vertical-align:top">User Guide</td>
                <td style="width:2%"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr >
                <td style="width:2%"></td>
                <td style="width:43%;text-align: left;text-transform: uppercase; color:#083A97"><h3>SIFT Interview Demo</h3></td>
                <td style="width:10%"></td>
                <td style="width:43%;text-align: left;text-transform: uppercase; color:#083A97"><h3>Interviewer quick reference guide</h3></td>
                <td style="width:2%"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggesting you to go with `<div>` based approach. Here is the solution from your current approach.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="overflow: auto">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1499084732479-de2c02d45fcc?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80" style="display:inline-block;max-width: 47%;min-width: 47%; float: left"/>
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1499084732479-de2c02d45fcc?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80" style="display:inline-block;max-width: 47%;min-width: 47%; float: right"/>
    </div>
    <div style="clear: both"></div>
    <div style="position:relative;  top: -20px;">
        <table style="table-layout: fixed ; width:100%;">
            <tr>
                <td style="width:2%"></td>
                <td style="width:43%;text-align: left;color:#00AFAB;vertical-align:top; background: #fff">SIFT Video</td>
                <td style="width:10%"></td>
                <td style="width:43%;text-align: left;color:#00AFAB;vertical-align:top; background: #fff">User Guide</td>
                <td style="width:2%"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr >
                <td style="width:2%"></td>
                <td style="width:43%;text-align: left;text-transform: uppercase; color:#083A97;"><h3>SIFT Interview Demo</h3></td>
                <td style="width:10%"></td>
                <td style="width:43%;text-align: left;text-transform: uppercase; color:#083A97"><h3>Interviewer quick reference guide</h3></td>
                <td style="width:2%"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```